# I can't find any resource for Amp dev

Tags: amp-html

I am trying to make a website project with AMP (google) but I did not find any resources and tutorials to help me with the development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean Yassine but the documentation from the website is a good place to start

[https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/?format=websites[Resources](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/?format=websites%5BResources) & Tutorials][1]